# install pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl for python 3.6

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I would like to install `pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` for `python 3.6(64 bit)`

I did download `wheel-0.30.0` and upgraded it

but  when i run :
`C:\Users\hp>pip install pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

i get:
`pygame-1.9.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

I would like to know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wheel is for the (unreleased, development) version 3.7 of CPython, on a 64-bit version of ms-windows.

Look [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and pick the wheel that matches your Python version and platform, where

- `cp27` → CPython 2.7
- `cp34` → CPython 3.4
- `cp35` → CPython 3.5
- `cp36` → CPython 3.6

and

- `win32` → 32-bit version of ms-windows
- `win_amd64` → 64-bit version of ms-windows